# How to install all updates without Internet?

Tags: windows-7, updates

I have Windows 7 Home Premium without internet access.  Is there a way I can download and install all of the updates that I would normally have gotten through Windows Update?  I can download from another machine and transfer using a USB drive, but I can't download anything locally (otherwise I'd use Windows Update).

The machine I can connect to the internet with is a Mac, not Windows.  So I can't use any Windows-specific software.

Comment: OK, allow me to clarify with an edit

Comment: Use a VM on the MAC to setup your own WSUS solution.

Comment: I thought about that, but I'd love a simple website download if it exists

Comment: You are not going to find software for OS X that was developed to download updates for Windows.  Most of the solutions in the duplicate can be implemented in a virtual machine though.

Comment: I'm working on that now, but it's taking forever to extract the VM...  I was looking for a website to download a service pack style package that can be executed in Windows, but eventually this VM will finish and I'll be updated.

Comment: Service Pack 1 is on Microsoft's website.  Any updates released after Service Pack 1 are individual updates and the duplicate question's solutions can be used to download them.

Comment: I am running WSUS in VMWare Fusion and it seems to be working so far.  Any idea if it will give me the little "Upgrade to Windows 10" app?

Comment: No; That won't be possible with WSUS.  If that is the reason you are trying to upgrade you should download the Media Creation Tool and just install Windows 10.  Be sure you activate Windows 10 by phone since your license is a digital hash of your hardware not a license key with build 10240

Comment: But will I get the free Win10 upgrade?  If not, then I'll just wait till I can drag the machine to somewhere with internet and let it do it's thing there.  I'm after the free Windows 10 upgrade, since it's less resource intensive.

Comment: My comment explains in detail how to upgrade to Windows 10.  Anyone running an eligible version of Windows, the upgrade to Windows 10 is free, until July 29th 2016.  It does not matter how you perform the upgrade.  You just have to do an in-place upgrade the first time on said machine in order to get a machine with the require digital license.

Comment: And it won't remove any of my data/programs?

Comment: Sorry if I seem over-worried about this, I had a bad experience upgrading to Win7 from WinXP.   :-/